# Put two elements next to each other and both still have margins

Tags: position, margin

I seem to have this problem a lot when i'm writing.  I have two elements on the same line.  I need them both to have margins and thus cannot set their positions to `absolute`.  if i don't set the position of the first element, it appears fine.  However, the second element will appear below the first element.  This is bad; I would like them to appear on the same line.  In other words I would like to set both of the elements to `position: absolute; top: 0;` but then i can't use margin, which i need.

HTML:

```
#userQuestion{
//border: 1px solid yellow;
width: 400px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 40px;
line-height: 1.28;
display: inline-block;
}

.container{
padding: 0;
margin 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
//border: 1px solid blue;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 480px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='userQuestion'></div>  //this is fine
<div class='container'></div>  //this appears underneath userQuestion.  I would like them to be on the same line.
```

Comment: how about good old 'table' :)  let the flames begin...

Comment: @randy could you make this an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
.container {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 480px;
}
```